# How do I "eliminate" every third element from a boolean array until only 1 is left as 'true'?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, boolean, iteration

I am trying to do a challenge question for school(I am a complete beginner so pls go easy on me). I need to recreate the game Duck-Duck-Goose. I ask the user for the number of players, create a boolean array of that particular number and then set them all to 'true'. I am trying to loop through a boolean array and gradually turn every third element to 'false'. Once it gets to the end of the array, I want it to go through the array again, repeating the same process. I am also having difficulty with setting the index as the next element( so if the 3rd element is reset to 'false' then the array starts counting at the 4th element), and then loop through the array again. The goal is to repeat this process (turning every 3rd element to 'false' until there is only one element left as 'true') in the array and then printing it.

*
I am limited to using boolean array only
*

Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Duck Duck Goose!!!");
System.out.println("Please enter the number of players:");
int players=scan.nextInt();
boolean [] game=new boolean[players];
for(int a=0;a<players;a++){ //set all players to 'true'
      game[a]=true;
  }
  if(players>=1){
    int turns=players-1;
      while(turns>=1){
        for(int i=0;i<players;i=i+3){
          if(game[i]=true){
          game[i]=false;
          turns--;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else{ // if there is less than 1 player, end the program
    System.out.println("Try to get more players!");
    System.exit(0);
  }
System.out.println("YaaaaY");
for(int j=0;j<players;j++){
  if(game[j]==true){ // look through the array and declare the winner
    System.out.println("The "+j+" player won!");
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

When I run this I get the following output:

*Welcome to the game of Duck Duck Goose!!!

Please enter the number of players:

10 (just for the example)

YaaaaY

The 1 player won!

The 2 player won!

The 4 player won!

The 5 player won!

The 7 player won!

The 8 player won!*

What am I doing wrong??? How can I make a loop go through the array multiple times and delete each third element? How do I make the loop not start at the beginning each time, but start at the index after an "eliminated" player? Should I not use a loop at at?

I'm at my wits end with this one. Any help is greatly appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to help you with everything in your main function.  Have you learned separate functions, yet?  How about static variables?

Suppose you had a function 
int nextActiveIndex(int currentIndex) {  ... }
which would treat your boolean array as a circle and would find the next true in the array, looping around if necessary.  So, if the array is five elements long, and currently has

```
0: F
1: T
2: T
3: F
4: T
```

nextActiveIndex(1) would be 2, and nextActiveIndex(2) would be 4, and nextActiveIndex(4) would be 1.

So your loop is not looping through your array, it is just looping the number of steps you want to make (in your example, 3 steps), and you then set that index to false.  Repeat until nextActiveIndex returns the number you pass in, because that means that it is the only true left.

One thing you'll need is for both your main function and your nextActiveIndex function to be able to see the array.  To do this, you make the array a static member of the class rather than just being declared inside the main function.

If you don't know about static member variables yet, then you'll have to pass the array in to nextActiveIndex as well as the current index.

Answer (score -1):

I would loop through the boolean array, one value at a time and instead have a count variable that goes to three but it only incremented after three true indexes, as opposed to any three indices like you have now.

```
        int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<game.length; i++) {
        if(game[i]) {
            count++;
        }

        if(count == 3) {
            game[i] = false;
        } else if(count == 4) {
            count = 0;
        }


    }
```